# How to know if an User has logged in SFMC using SFMC APIs or SSJS scripts

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

We are creating a cloud page where only the users who have access to SFMC can access and login to the page. If the user is currently not logged into SFMC then, when the user opens the Cloudpage it will ask him to login via SFMC login page be it via SSO or MFA what ever is his preferred option. So is there a way to check if an user has logged into SFMC or not using SFMC APIs or SSJS scripts?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://sfmarketing.cloud/2021/08/09/securing-marketing-cloud-apps-hosted-on-cloudpages/amp/

Comment: Yeep this is what I was searching for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Audit Trail](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_audit_trail.htm&type=5) enabled and data has been collect after a period of time, you should be able to retrieve this information via REST API or SSJS.

`Email Studio > Admin > Security Settings > Enable Audit Trail Data Collection: Yes`

Once that's enabled, the REST API endpoint is:

`YOURTENANT.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/audit/auditEvents`

You can leverage this REST API endpoint in a Script Activity to mirror this data to a Data Extension.  These are the properties returned:

```
id
createdDate
memberId
enterpriseId
employee.id
employee.employeeName
employee.userName
objectType.id
objectType.name
operation.id
operation.name
object.id
object.name
transactionId
```

Comment: Thanks Adam... We will check and see if we can use this in our cloudpage or not...Is there anyother way to achieve this without enabling Audit Trail?

Comment: Audit trail doesn't require CloudPage changes.  If the CloudPages are gated with a SFMC login, the Audit Trail will record them.  You could insert rows into Data Extensions with scripting in your CloudPages if you want, but that's something you'd need to implement on every CloudPage.  I would not recommend doing that.